# Mongoose share model schema for multiple database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multi-tenant, mongoose-schema

I am trying to implement multi-tenant in my application.Every tenant will be having a separate database. I have planned to change/switch the mongoose database connection dynamically for each client based on the sub-domain name using [`mongoose.useDb`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/3.7-%28unstable%29-Release-Notes#connection-pool-sharing) method. Do i need to recompile mongoose model schema when every db is change/switched using `useDb`?. And is there any alternative way to accomplish this task by sharing the schema across multiple db connections .Any help will be really appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this or figure something out? I have the same, struggling with the same issue. As I see it, if you create your models on the default connection, the Schemas are available, but the models are not. So maybe you have to iterate each schema and reinstantiate for each tenant database?

Comment: Devendiran Kumar, @TremendusApps I am also struggling the same issue. Have you found the solution for best connection to multiple databases in multi-tenant app?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily use multiple connections with `Mongoose` as defined in the specs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections

You just have to set the models to each connection. But as models are compiled for each connection - you should have some proper functionality to share that code. It could be very basic, like describing the Schema in simple objects and then populate it to your specific connection:

```
var UserSchema = {
    name: String
}

var connection1 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/connection1');
connection1.model('User', mongoose.Schema(UserSchema));

var connection2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/connection2');
connection2.model('User', mongoose.Schema(UserSchema));
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question. Your answer addresses creating new connections. His question is to use the SAME connection, but switch databases using his existing connections `useDb()` function. Its material because it affects the number of connections in the pool, possibly substantially

Comment: Yeah I guess it mostly answers this part `And is there any alternative way to accomplish this task by sharing the schema across multiple db connections` :)

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a condition that runs after the user's login to determine to which database the system should connect.